# items are not displayed after grouping in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, grouping, itemscontrol

I've added grouping to ItemsControl:

```
        <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource SellingDashboardToDosList}" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="#C7E8F8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ToDoList}" >
            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}">
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </GroupBox>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Now I see only empty GroupBoxes. I've used Snoop tool to explore the application and I found out that GroupBox ItemPresenters are empty! What could be the reason of it?

If I remove the grouping from the ItemsControl (the ItemsControl.GroupStyle element), then everything works fine, and I see all items again. I don't need to make any changes to the underlying data context to see all items. The data context (the ItemsSource binging) is of type **CollectionViewSource**.

The binding tracing is turned on, but I don't see any binding errors.

Comment: Style works for me with sample data. Just have a look at the grouping field data.

Comment: What should I look for? Right now the groups' ItemsPresenters are empty. Why?

Comment: can u upload some sample code what u have tried with some data?

Comment: It can't be done fast. I will attempt to do it later.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ItemsControl style was overriding ItemsControl.Template property. The problem was solved once that style got overridden.

Comment: Just in order to complete the solution, better set the "ItemsPanel" with the proper "ItemsPanelTemplate" rather than overriding the ItemControl template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group your data first. Use CollectionViewSource to do that:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Data" Source="{StaticResource SellingDashboardToDosList}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PropertyNameToGroupBy"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

And only then you can do the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Biding Source={StaticResource Data}}" ...
```

Comment: The data context is CollectionViewSource, only it is generated in C# instead of XAML. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier. Thank you for your willingness to help.

Comment: Yes. The problem was with styles, not with data source.